# How to create a label for an alias account in corporate Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I have a corporate Gmail account: "pedro@business.com" and in my company Gmail account we have an alias, "ab@business.com".

I need to figure out a way to make all emails from my supplier (x@supplier.com) that are sent to "ab@business.com" to go to a specific label. And every one in my corporation who has access to this alias must see what's in this label.

So far I tried to apply the label "Invoice" when this happens: `from: (x@supplier.com) to: (ab@business.com)`. But this doesn't work, because I'm applying this to my own inbox (pedro@business.com) and I need to create the label for my alias, not for me.

Does any one know how to do it or if it's even possible?

Comment: This sounds like a great reason not to use an alias....

Comment: @aparente001 Do you know other way to do that?

Comment: Perhaps you could create a separate Gmail account for communication with this supplier, and then have it forward to your primary account.